Wheel Speed Sensor Direction
2000 BMW E39 520i, Touring
After snapping the mounting bolt of a rear wheel speed sensor, then attempting to drill the bolt, and use a screw extractor, only for the bolt extractor to snap inside the bolt (really stuck!) I am considering an alternative idea.
If I drilled a new mounting hole for the wheel speed sensor and tapped it, then installed a new sensor, but at a roughly 25 degree angle from standard, would it still work correctly, or does the sensor need to be in a specific orientation?
Thank you.

I'm unclear about the 25 degree angle. Do you mean, for example, if the original speed sensor was at the 3 o'clock position on the tone ring, you want to install it at the 4 o'clock position? And you'll mount it at the same distance away from the tone ring and perpendicular to it just like the original? All yes?

As long as the gap and alignment are still correct, it should still work. That said, it's still a better idea to get the broken bolt out, and repair threads if necessary. I'd recommend applying heat and using the "weld a nut on" method.
Don't feel too bad about the situation, these sensor mounting bolts break off like this all the time. Even getting the sensor out of the hole is usually a challenge.

I just had the same problem with an Escape - I used a helicoil and it works great. That would be my first option. I got a helicoil that would allow me to use the same size bolt as the original.
I'm not sure about mounting it with a different orientation, I guess it depends on how the magnets are oriented with the tone ring. I wouldn't do it.
